# enhance sql script performance

Tags: sql, db2

I need to enhance below SQL script to have better performance.
Is there any suggestion?

Purpose:
To filter out Table_1 record which have keywords in Table_2.

Example:

```
Table_1 have data: "xxxyyyzzz" and "aaabbbccc"
Table_2 have data: "%xxyy%"
Result: "xxxyyyzzz" will be filter out and "aaabbbccc" will be return in query.
```

Statistic:

```
Table_1 with 1,000,000 record
Table_2 with 2,250 record
```

Current result:
Return 100 record in 800 sec

Script as below:

```
select * from table_1
minus
select * from table_1 a
where exists
(select 1 from table_2 b
where a.field_1  like b.field_1);
```

Comment: Is the data in table_2 used as pattern in a LIKE predicate as shown or are those fields exact matches (no LIKE needed)?

Answer (score 1):

you can write this with using join

```
   select * from table_1 a
   inner join table_2 b on a.field_1  = b.field_1
```

for optimization you can go through below link :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35665/Top-steps-to-optimize-data-access-in-SQL-Serv

Comment: You'd need a "like" , not an  "=", but I agree

Answer (score 0):

Two things to recommend here:

- Indexes
- Denormalization

One thing people tend to do when databases get massive is invoke **Denormalization**. This is when you store the data from multiple tables in one table to prevent the need to do a `join`. This is useful if your application relies on specific reads to power it. It is a commonly used tactic when scaling.

If `Denormalization` is out of the question, another, simpler way to optimize this query would be to make sure you have **indexes** on the columns you are running the `join`and `like` against. Indexing the columns for the `like` would have a huge impact, you will immediately notice an increase in performance.
Also using `SELECT *` is really bad practice and does create a performance hit, change that up by specifying which columns you want to return!

Any other optimizations I would need some more information about the data, hope it helps!